# How to toggle(add/remove) the form-control from angular reactive form if the field is hidden using ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a scenario to show different set of form fields based on a radio button checked. The fields on display will have required validation. But when it is not displayed, the validation and value entered should be removed and the form-control should not be part of the submitted form value.
The form-control should be added and removed based on radio button toggle.

What are the ways to achieve this in angular reactive form.

Sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-demo-3n5sdz

Comment: What have you tried, can you share some code?

Comment: you need to disable them.

Comment: @AndreiTătar will disabling actually remove the form-control from the form-group?

Comment: @Manojkumar disabled fields will not be validated and form.values will not return them.

Comment: @AndreiTătar It's working.. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is there a way to mention this while defining the form-control

Comment: @Chellappanவ , dhanasekar added sample code link in the question with suggestions from Andrei. It is working fine. Any other ways to achieve this as my original code has many nested form-group to be enabled/disabled

Comment: If you want to disable by default you can set disable property to formcontrol:  this.eventEditForm = this.fb.group({
         completed:[{value: '', disabled : true},Validators.required],
         first:['',Validators.required],
         second:[,Validators.required]
       })

Comment: @Chellappanவ thank u. I also have one more scenario where i need to make the input field readonly but have the value in form.value. I was using the disabled property for this but just noticed that the form field is missing from form.value. Can you suggest how to make the field read only and also retain the form-control value.

Added the sample code link.

Comment: if you want to get value of disabled form control you have to call getRawValue on form. doc:https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue